# LDA on text data, trying to recover the job title on bad spelling

Tags: python, text, lda

I'm working on a DataFrame **using Python** that contains data from different people. One of the columns contains the "Current Job" (as a string). I would like to classify the different kinds of jobs that this DataFrame contains.
But I have some issues with these columns:

- Bad spelling
- Non-existing jobs (for example one of the jobs is "Spinning in my chair").
- It's Spanish, so you can find jobs as "**operario**", "**operaria**".
- Some jobs are written in different ways (but they are basically the same job) such as "**operario de máquinas**", "**operario de maquinaria**".

Stemming can deal with similar words such as "**operario**" and "**operaria**" but I would like to know if there are some other tools that I can learn to deal with this kind of problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you need `fuzzy searching` to check if words are similar.

Comment: You can use character ngrams which will find groups of subword units. You can also use byte-pair encoding which is more popular in neural approaches, but can definitely be applied to non-neural models. Finally, you can use real morphological analyzers.